# Can't restore model with tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose applied

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to restore a model using following code:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, model_path)
g=tf.get_default_graph()
```

And for each weight or bias in original graph, I did `g.get_tensrr_by_name()`. 
But when I tried to do this on a `deconv2d` layer, which is something like below:

```
def deconv2d(self,inputs, num_outputs, kernel_shape, g,scope,strides=[1, 1]):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope) as scope:
    weights_initializer = g.get_tensor_by_name("prsr/conditioning/deconv/Conv2d_transpose/weights:0")
    biases_initializer = g.get_tensor_by_name("prsr/conditioning/deconv/Conv2d_transpose/biases:0")
    return tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose(inputs=inputs, num_outputs=num_outputs,kernel_size=kernel_shape,stride=strides, \
      padding='SAME', weights_initializer=weights_initializer,biases_initializer=biases_initializer)
```

it failed and showed following error:

```
  File "restore.py", line 41, in deconv2d
    padding='SAME', weights_initializer=weights_initializer,biases_initializer=biases_initializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 177, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1126, in convolution2d_transpose
    outputs = layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 323, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 289, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py", line 1043, in build
    dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1033, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 932, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 349, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 278, in variable_getter
    variable_getter=functools.partial(getter, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 228, in _add_variable
    trainable=trainable and self.trainable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1327, in layer_variable_getter
    return _model_variable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1316, in _model_variable_getter
    custom_getter=getter, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 177, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 259, in model_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 177, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py", line 214, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 341, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 638, in _get_single_variable
    raise ValueError("If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.")
ValueError: If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.
```

I don't know which `shape` does this refer to, and I don't think `weights_initializer` and `biases_initializer` are constants, they are tensors, right? By the way, I'm very sure that those two tensors, `prsr/conditioning/deconv/Conv2d_transpose/weights` and `prsr/conditioning/deconv/Conv2d_transpose/biasess` exist in the original graph, since I checked this using `print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file`, and I can actually see the values.
So how can I restore model which applies this `tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose()` layer? I searched a lot on both stackoverflow and github, but nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`weights_initializer` and `bias_initializer` are not what you think they are. You probably think of those two tensors as the initial values for the weights used in the deconvolution, right? However, the initializer argument is a *function* not a tensor that should look something like this:

```
def my_initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32, partition_info=None):
    # do some computation to build up a tensor of the given shape
    return that_tensor
```

You could then use this initializer like so:

```
tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose(inputs=inputs, ..., weights_initializer=my_initializer)
```

So, as a solution to your problem, I think the following should work:

```
def weights_initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32, partition_info=None):
    weights = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("prsr/conditioning/deconv/Conv2d_transpose/weights:0")
    return weights
```

This feels a bit hacky in my opinion, though. Why do you want to load a graph and then use pre-trained weights in a new operation? Why are those weights not associated with this operation before already when you set up the initial model?

PS: When dealing with variables you might find `tf.get_variable` come in handy. If you create variables using `tf.get_variable` you can later retrieve those variables with `tf.get_variable` again, without having to call the cumbersome `get_tensor_by_name`. Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope#understanding_tfget_variable) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried what you said, but still not working. And the reason why I did this is because I got trouble in restoring value of a node in the computational graph of tensorflow. Can you please take a look at this screenshot? [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/12n6wug39t39zoy/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-05%20at%206.09.10%20PM.png?dl=0) I was attempting to restore that "c_logits" node, I actually can do `node=g.get_tensor_by_name("prsr/conditioning/conv/c_logits:0")`, then `sess.run(node)`, but the value is different from what it should be.

Comment: Holy, I'm so sorry, I figured out what's going on. I was feeding the input to a wrong node! Now it's perfectly working! Thank you!